# Bootstrap dropdown not working and not dropping down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I'm making a small VueJS page which will be a SPA. Dropdown won't work. No matter how much I copy from the bootstrap guide or read their recommendations. It just doesn't. What I'm missing?

They say popper.js it's included in bootstrap.min.js
They say you need to wrap the thing in a .dropdown element
Read in SO questions that jQuery needs to be before bootstrap js, did also that one

I copied their example.
No luck.

Thank you

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown button
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wanderer">
    <ul v-for="todo in todos">
      <li>{{todo.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var wandererApp = new Vue({
      el: '#wanderer',
      data: {
        todos: [{
            text: 'AAAAAA'
          },
          {
            text: 'ZZZZZZZ'
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I removed your rant. It's not appropriate here. It's also off the mark, since the error was yours. Be sure to use the correct docs for the library you're loading. It helps clear all that up if you tag your Bootstrap version per the instructions in the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag.

Comment: Also, jQuery isn't needed for Bootstrap 5. It's recommended by most devs that you purge it from your app unless you _really_ need it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why your dropdown menu isn't working is because you are using a 5.0 Bootstrap CDN and pairing it with the old 4.0 syntax. You need to change the syntax to match the 5.0 CDN. I have typed it below. You can include your to-do list afterwards if this helps.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
          </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: To be more clear, the data attributes are missing the `-bs` substring.

Comment: same problem overhere, copieing the examples from Bootstrap. The bs did the thing.