# Bootstrap 5 multiple dropdowns don't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Before you complain about my imports here are they:

```
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

I have the following problem - my dropdown don't open at all and in the webtools it shows the underlying HTML as invisible all the time. My HTML is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 header-company">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand reflection-container" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
      <img src="/" alt="Logo" id="logo" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" style="margin-top: 75px;position:static;">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test1">TEST1</a>
        </li>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark nav-headlines" data-toggle="dropdown" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test2">TEST2</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu navbarSupportedContent">
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test3">TEST3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test4">TEST4</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test5">TEST5</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test6">TEST6</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test7">TEST7</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test8">TEST8</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="/Test9" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark nav-headlines" data-toggle="dropdown">TEST9</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines nav-divider" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test10">TEST10</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/Test11">TEST11</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: _Please_ stop using inline styles. They're a huge pain for everyone. Then, your HTML has issues. Any good editor will point out that you're missing a closing list tag. That's probably not your issue here, but it needs fixing. And your imports list doesn't tell us much. We can't see which version of Bootstrap you're loading. I'm guessing that it's not the bundle (which contains PopperJS).

Comment: As you can see with the demo snippet I created from your code, your dropdowns work fine if you include the necessary libraries. See [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns).

Comment: FYI, most of your inline styles could be replaced by [Bootstrap spacing utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/).

Comment: I messed up, it seems I'm using Bootstrap v5.1.0 is that the issue?

Comment: I rewrote the code from a codebase using Bootstrap 4, and this is using Bootstrap 5 in the bundle

Comment: You aren't using Bootstrap 5. Your markup and data attributes are BS4. I suggest that you close this question, address the suggestions I made, and review your markup to be sure it matches the _appropriate_ documentation exactly.

Comment: See [Bootstrap dropdown not working and not dropping down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859520/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-and-not-dropping-down) and many similar questions.

Comment: I mean I noticed I'm importing a bundle of BS5 instead of BS4.

Comment: Votes reflect the value of the question to the community. There isn't much here. You have a number of mistakes which means a lack of focus within the question.

Comment: And you still haven't updated your post title _or_ tags to reflect Bootstrap 5. I'm not sure what you're asking at this point.

Comment: Now it's fixed. And basically all I had to do is to change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and remove the unnecessary buttons

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the top part of your post you have made a point of showing that Bootstrap 5 is implemented. But all of your HTML is formatted for Bootstrap 4 and you are implementing that too along wtih Bootstrap 5?

Comment: @CuteCodeRob I copy-pasted the code from Bootstrap 4, hence the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 requires Popper.js as mentioned in documentation as well.

So be sure to include Popper.js before Bootstrap js file.

Comment: There's no popper.js in this bundle, I'm guessing it's included already in the package

Comment: This file is included through CDN bootstrap bundle does not have it read in documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: You can also include bootstrap.bundle.min.js then you don't need to add Popper.js

Comment: tried that, didn't help

Comment: try adding Popper.js after jquery and before bootstrap and then check the console for errors if any.

Comment: tried that, there's no errors whatsoever

Comment: https://codepen.io/ghazniali95/pen/RwjeMvQ

I am attaching a codepen you can get help dropdown is working fine using bootstrap 4.

Comment: The codepen only contains one dropdown and I have two

Comment: I have updated the code now you have two dropdowns in navbar.

Comment: sorry, I added the wrong code, editing the question now